# Angular: Setting variables inside $on events, need to call $apply?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using an angular module then sends messages and I am trying to set a variable to true or false but I notice that they do not get updated in the UI unless I wrap them inside a $apply. Is this the best way of doing this?

This is my working code, remove the $apply and although the variable is updated - the view never updates.

```
  $scope.$on('duScrollspy:becameActive', ($event, $element, $target) => {
        $scope.$apply(() => {
          this.ready = true;
        });
    });
```

Anyone any ideas on the best way to fix this? Calling $apply seems like a code smell, I know listening for events on the scope isn't considered good practice but this is a third party Angular module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the scope inside an event requires a call to $apply().
(`this` is bound to the scope btw)

There's no way around it. (if you need the view updated.)

`$apply` is actually called automatically in many places like $http promise resolve code (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js line 1331-1351) but it's not called on events.

Note, line numbers may change. Search for `function done()`

So this is not code smell, this is standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely the `this` keyword. It's important to remember that `this` changes it's meaning depending on the context in which it is used. You probably think that `this` is referring to your controller, or service, or whatever object you have defined your listener inside of. That's why you see this common pattern of naming the controller as the very first statement:

```
function MyController($scope, $rootScope) {
  var vm = this;

  $scope.$on('duScrollspy:becameActive', ($event, $element, $target) => {
    vm.ready = true;
    // or 
    $scope.ready = true
    // is better than
    this.ready = true;
  });
}
```

Comment: No, I am using ES2015 and babel.. This is This

Comment: But I am using ControllerAs syntax, I thought this is provided over $scope

Comment: The fat arrow operator is meant to keep the original `this` in the correct context

Comment: It is provided over $scope, I just wanted to suggest using scope instead of controller, if you are having issues

Comment: Btw, have you console.logged `this` just to be sure it is actually the controller?